# Postgres trigger/check contraint order

Tags: database, postgresql

If trigger is `BEFORE` I guess trigger will run before the check constraint.

But what is the order if trigger is `AFTER`? Does the check run first?

Comment: `before` triggers -> non-deffered constraints -> `after` triggers (if constraints passed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't guess, know [Create Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html):

> The trigger can be specified to fire before the operation is attempted on a row (before constraints are checked and the INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE is attempted); or after the operation has completed (after constraints are checked and the INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE has completed); ...